# How to force 2 divs to be always superposed?

Tags: html, css

**CODE:**

```
<div class = "homeTitleBack">TITLE</div>
<div class="homeTitle">
    <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
    <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
    <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
</div>

.homeTitle {
  z-index: 14;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #252B37;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  width: 550px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.homeTitleBack {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  top: 25vh;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 20px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5vw);
  -moz-filter: blur(5vw);
  -ms-filter: blur(5vw);
  filter: blur(5vw);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}
```

---

**QUESTION:**

How to force `homeTitle` and `homeTitleBack` to always have the same center ?

I need the 2 divs to always stay superposed and their distance from the top should vary thanks to vh.

**EDIT:** Added CSS.

Comment: By *always have the same center* you mean they should be centered both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: What's happening now instead of what you want? What's causing them to not be superposed? (I suppose you could make them both absolutely positioned; have you tried that?)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Absolutely. Let me add the current css I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use `text-align: center`:

```css
.homeTitleBack, .homeTitle {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "homeTitleBack">TITLE</div>
<div class="homeTitle">
  <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
  <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
  <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
</div>
```

If the above doesn't work for you, something is changing default, normal rendering of those `<div>`s. So there's `CSS` you're not showing us.

To make sure they have the same center both horizontally and vertically, you want to place them both in a container.

```css
[center-everything]  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 40vh;
}

[center-everything]>div:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* the below are just resets for SO, you shouldn't normally need them */
body { margin: 0;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<div center-everything>
  <div class = "homeTitleBack">TITLE</div>
  <div class="homeTitle">
    <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
    <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
    <span class="WORD">TEST</span>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: There was a misunderstanding.

Comment: See if the second part covers your needs. You can set the `min-height: 100vh;` of the container to whatever suits your use case.

Comment: This update is much better :D but it seems you are forcing both divs to be centered in the middle of the screen ? I would like their center to be the same and their height to be set in `vh` like I currently do.

Comment: Yes, you need a minimal height on parent if you want to center vertically. If you don't you will center vertically, but the children, being centered will go above the parent. What happens is they go above the start of page and create a space that's unscrollable. If you need more details i can provide an example. What you want to do is set the `min-height` or `height` property of `[center-everything]` to a value that's convenient for your use-case.

Comment: @Coder1000 I updated second solution based on what you added to question. Remove the `top-margin` from `.homeTitleBack` and with my code you should be set. As a side-note, adding hard-coded widths to your elements (like 800px) will ruin responsiveness. You should really wrap that in a `@media` query.